# Trying to save managed context object after deleting all objects causes app crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I am trying to save managed context object after deleting all the data or saving new data in 1 entity but it causes the app to crash in about 1% of cases but works fine 99% times.

edit: I am unable to debug because no crashes have happened while I am testing the app, We have inbuilt Crash reporting tool in the app, and it is reporting these crashes.

Logs:

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x237e3ae6 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreData                       0x25762193 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _validatePropertiesWithError:] + 310
2  CoreData                       0x25762039 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _validateForSave:] + 120
3  CoreData                       0x25761f97 -[NSManagedObject validateForInsert:] + 86
4  CoreData                       0x257615af -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _validateObjects:forOperation:error:exhaustive:forSave:] + 2362
5  CoreData                       0x25760b3b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _validateChangesForSave:] + 154
6  CoreData                       0x25760867 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _prepareForPushChanges:] + 270
7  CoreData                       0x25754be1 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 420
```

This is my fun:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let myFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")

        do {
            if let myResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(myFetchRequest) as? [MyEntity] {
                for myObject in myResults {
                    managedContext.deleteObject(myObject)
                }
            }
            try managedContext.save() // Most crashes at this line
            managedContext.reset()    // Some crashes at this line
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

Infant these random crashes are happening at multiple locations in the app, most of them while trying to save managed context object and a few while doing managedcontext.reset().

All the crashes are occurring on iOS 9.

PS- This is the first time I am working on iOS development and core data. I am using mostly the code added by Xcode in AppDelegate to handle Core Data. I have only added 1 line:

```
let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
    }
```

Comment: Post the debugger output

Comment: Also - are you running any of this in a background queue?

Comment: @Russell: No, all on the main thread.

Comment: @rckoenes I have edited my question, I can't give debugger output as I have not faced any crashes myself.

Comment: @AnshumanSrivastava Then any crash log will help.

Comment: And change your catch to actually output the error.  That will help to get the feedback you need to understand why it is failing.

Comment: @rckoenes I have updated the logs in the question.